# How to remove Duplicate items from siblings filter in Fluent Vapor 4?

Tags: vapor, vapor-fluent, server-side-swift

I have a query in Fluent Vapor that applies siblings filters based on metaTagIds. Here's the code snippet:

```swift
let queryBuilder = Attraction.query(on: req.db)
if let metaTagIds = attractionSearch.metaTagIds, metaTagIds.count > 0 {
    queryBuilder.join(siblings: \.$metaTags)
    queryBuilder.filter(MetaTag.self, \.$id ~~ metaTagIds)
}
```

After applying these siblings filters, I want to remove duplicate values from the queryBuilder. How can I achieve this in Fluent Vapor?

Any help or guidance would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: I can't try at the moment, but does this work on joins? https://docs.vapor.codes/fluent/query/?h=uniq#unique

Comment: I've already tried using the unique() method, but unfortunately, it doesn't seem to be functioning as expected.